# instantiate parameters to evaluate function definitions

Tags: coq

I'm working on a single `.v` file and I found it convenient to define things with parameters and definitions like this:

```
Parameter n : nat.
Definition n_plus_1 := n + 1.
```

rather than `Definition n_plus_1 (n : nat) = n + 1.`

My use cases are more complicated than this, but the idea is the same. Although defining things with parameters helped me write some proofs I'm interested in, sometimes I'd like to just test the definitions with actual values to make sure they actually compute what I intended. For example, with the example I just wrote, I can't do `Compute n_plus_1 3`. In some sense, I want to instantiate the parameter `n`. What'd be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way is to use the `Section` mechanism [modules would also work]:

```
Section With_N.
Variable n : nat.
Definition n_plus_1 := n + 1.
End With_N.

Compute (n_plus_1 3).
```

Comment: I didn't know about modules. I tried to do it with modules, but got stuck here:

```Module Type Sig.
Parameter n : nat.
Definition n_plus_1 := n + 1.
End Sig.

Module ModuleInstance <: Sig.
Definition n := 3.
End ModuleInstance.
```

It complaints about the definition of `n_plus_1` when I try to execute `End ModuleInstance`. How can I fix it?